# How to check if Accounts UI widget loaded on client?

Tags: meteor

The default Accounts-UI widget takes a while to load. I want to check on the client when it is ready, so that I can perform some DOM manipulations on it afterwards. I am currently using a timer like so:

```
Template.sign_in_modal.onRendered(function (){
  Tracker.afterFlush(function () {
    Meteor.setTimeout(function () {
        $('a#login-sign-in-link').click();
        $('a#login-name-link').click();   
        $('a.login-close-text').remove();       
    }, 100);
  });
});
```

The above hack works locally (probably because it loads faster) but not when I push to [saturnapi.com](https://saturnapi.com). I just want it to be expanded by default as shown below. Is there a way to ensure the UI widget is fully loaded via a template helper or otherwise make it expanded by default?

[image]

Comment: `loginButtons` template `onRendered` callback???

Comment: @Sasikanth that will not work. `onRendered` is extremely misleading and does not ensure that the DOM elements are present on the page. Please see my answer below.

Comment: @Sasikanth can you point me to documentation on that? Thanks

Comment: @FullStack, there is no documentation for that, `loginButtons` is a template so every template can have `onRendered` callback i.e; `Template.loginButtons.onRendered(function(){  })`, I just thought like that. I recommend to try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest checking when the `<a id="login-sigin-in-link"></a>` is added to the DOM. This could be verified by checking `$('a#login-sign-in-link').length`. If the element is on the DOM do your manipulation.

However if it is not just check again in a few milliseconds. I would suggest using `setInterval()`.

See below for the complete solution:

```
Template.sign_in_modal.onRendered(function (){
  var setIntervalId = Meteor.setInterval(function() {
    if($('a#login-sign-in-link').length) {
      $('a#login-sign-in-link').click();
      $('a.login-close-text').remove();
      Meteor.clearInterval(setIntervalId);
    }
  }, 100);
});

Template.sign_in_modal.onDestroyed(function() {
  $('.modal-backdrop.fade.in').remove();
});
```

Some may think that using `loginButtons.onRendered(function(){});` is a good way to verify if the element has been added to the DOM, but it is not. If you try to do the same DOM manipulation in `onRendered`, it will throw an `afterFlush error`. The `onRendered` function has been extremely misleading.

Comment: Works for now, though it's still a hack. Thanks